# How can I push DNS entries from my OpenVPN server to my OpenVPN clients?

Tags: openvpn

I've created a Windows Server on Azure and am running an OpenVPN server.  I'd like my clients to be able to access network resources on this server using its hostname.  I really only need to have one DNS entry pushed to the clients.

I created a DNS server on this machine and added some entries, but I'm not sure how I can have my OpenVPN clients use them.  I've tried using the **push** option below (where 10.8.0.1) is my OpenVPN network address.

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

But my network adapter on my client isn't pointing to this:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-71-26-85-4C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8d3d:edb3:f32e:4d92%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, February 4, 2018 12:51:20 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, February 4, 2019 12:51:20 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.5
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 469827441
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-36-08-3C-54-8C-A0-A3-15-63
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.6
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: the answer is in the OpenVPN's client configuration file.